# Show only login user data

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

This is my `setting.php` code:

```
<?php session_start();
include 'conn.php';
include '../includes/layouts/header.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header("location:signin.php");
}
if(isset($_SESSION['update']))
{
    echo $_SESSION['update'];
    unset($_SESSION['update']);
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM signup";
$qry=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($qry);
?>

    <div id="main">
        <div id="navigation">
            <div class="">
                Welcome to LMS
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="application.php">Send Leave Application</a></li>
                            <li><a href="setting.php">Setting</a></li>
                            <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
            </div>
        &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div id="page">


            <form method="post" action="update.php">
                <div class="reg_section">
                    <h3>Your Personal Information</h3>

                    <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $rows[1];?>" placeholder="First Name"><br>
                    <input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $rows[2];?>" placeholder="Last Name"><br>
                    <input type="text" name="uname" value="<?php echo $rows[3];?>" placeholder="Desired Username"><br>
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $rows[4];?>" placeholder="Email"><br>
                    <input type="text" name="department" value="<?php echo $rows[5];?>" placeholder="Department"><br>
                    <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $rows[6];?>" placeholder="Id #"/><br>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $rows[7];?>" placeholder="Phone #"/><br>

                </div>
                <div class="reg_section">
                    <h3>Your Password</h3>
                    <input type="password" name="pass" value="<?php echo $rows[8];?>" placeholder="Your Password"><br>
                    <input type="password" name="cpass" value="<?php echo $rows[8];?>" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                </div>
                <div class="reg_section">
                    <h3>Your Address</h3>
                    <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $rows[9];?>" placeholder="Address">
                </div>
                <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Info"></p>

            </form>

        </div>
    </div>





<?php include '../includes/layouts/footer.php' ?>
```

and this is the `Update.php` code:

```
<?php session_start();
include 'conn.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $user=$_POST['uname'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $depart=$_POST['department'];
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];
    $msg="Record Update Successfuly";
    $qry="UPDATE  signup SET First_Name='$fname',Last_Name='$lname',Username='$user',Email='$email',Department='$depart',Employe_Id='$id',Phone='$phone',Password='$pass',Address='$address' WHERE Username='$user'";

    if(mysql_query($qry))
    {

        header('location:setting.php');
        echo $_SESSION['update']=$msg;
    }
    else
    {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
}
?>
```

now, I want that only logged-in users can change their record and the form should contain their own data, but I can't.
When I log into the page then it will only show the first record of the database, but I want  it to show only the logged-in user record.
How can I do it?

......

Comment: What is with `$sql="SELECT * FROM signup";`? why are you not using `where clause` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't go into the discussion of using `mysql` when you should consider adoptiing `mysqli` or `pdo`.

You are selecting all records within you query. You only need to select the desired one. Assuming that you are setting the user is within the session you could call it like so.

Eg: `$sql="SELECT * FROM signup WHERE userId = '$_SESSION['userId']'";`